# Удаление пробелов с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Имеем следующий текст

```
string s = "5  342  234 euro";
```

Вопрос, как из данного текста, с помощью регулярного выражения удалить пробелы в сумме, но оставить 1 пробел между суммой и валютой.
Имея следующий шаблон регулярного выражения `string patten = @"\s";`
Мы удалим все пробелы. Быть может, можно как-то задать шаблон, который не будет участвовать в последующем удалении пробелов? Что-то вроде `string patten = @"\s(\seuro)";` (где всё, что подходит под `\seuro` удалено не будет.
В итоге я должен получить такую строку `5342234 euro`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\s+(?!euro)
```

Конструкция `(?!euro)`, называется "zero-width negative lookahead". Она означает, что пробел сматчится только в том случае если сразу за ним *не* следует `euro`.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
var input = "5  342  234 euro";
var pattern @"\s+(?!euro)";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, ""); //5342234 euro
```

На случай, если кроме euro могут быть названия других валют, лучше использовать такую регулярку `\s+(?![^\d\s])`. Под неё подпадает пробел, за которым не следует цифра или еще один пробел. Так мы не только удалим пробелы между разрядами, но еще удалим лишние пробелы перед наименованием валюты, если их окажется больше одного. Например `"5  342  234   рублей" => "5342234 рублей"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Regex.Replace("5  342  234 euro", @"(?<=\d+)\s+(?=\d+)", "");
```

Другой вариант. Удаляет пробелы между любыми числами, не только перед `euro`.

---

Здесь `\s` соответствует пробельному символу, `\d` - десятичной цифре. `+` после `\s` и `\d` позволяет находить элементы, которые повторяются один и более раз.

Конструкции `(?<=subexpression)` и `(?=subexpression)` — это утверждения положительного просмотра назад и вперед. Они проверяют символы, непосредственно предшествующие текущему, и символы, непосредственно следующие за текущим, на соответствие заданному `subexpression`.